# package update in ubuntu on vitual box

Tags: virtualbox

while following one of the tutorials I needed to install a curl package. Here are my system configuration:

Virtualbox 4.1 on Windows 7 64 bit. I have installed ubuntu 12.04 on the virtual box.

When I try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

I see the following errors:

```
[sudo] password for userMe: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package curl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'curl' has no installation candidate
userMe@userMe-ubuntu:~$
```

When I try the same on a direct installation of ubuntu on a laptop (not a virtual machine) there is no problem.

I am assuming this may be because of network settings. Please note that my work PC is in a corporate network and uses auto proxy settings (using a .pac file) for internet access etc.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is **main** repository activated? Did you `sudo apt-get update` your package list?

Comment: Can the VM connect to the Internet? Open a web browser in the VM and connect to Google or Yahoo.

Comment: Yes. I set up the proxy in the ubuntu firefox exactly like my windows 7 IE settings and internet access from firefox runs just fine. I was wondering if ubuntu knows to use these proxyies as needed. not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing `sudo apt-get update` first, and then try to install.  If this is a new installation into VBox, then this sometimes is necessary.

Second, if the issue does not get resolved, make sure you have the "main" repository active.  You can check this from within Synaptic, which is a package manager, or by going and checking `/etc/apt/sources.list` for a line that has the ubuntu archive mirror and 'main' on the same line.

If none of these options help, and 'main' is active, then you may just not be able to given your IT policies and firewall settings on your corporate network.

Comment: Yes I tried the sudo apt-get update and this is what I see

userMe@userMe-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for ayusman: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
userMe@userMe-ubuntu:~$

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Are you running anything else?  Synaptic or the Ubuntu Software Center at the same time?  Because both of those lock out the others from using apt-related stuff

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [php5-curl [image: Install php5-curl]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/php5-curl), either by clicking that link, or running these commands in the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Answer (score 0):

After some hit and trial.
This solution worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838177/package-update-in-ubuntu-on-vitual-box

It seems like the network related issues may be there, especially working from behind a firewall or corporate reverse proxy. May differ for others.

Hope this helps somebody.